# Is there any way of viewing the CD Key for a bundle on Steam?

Tags: steam

I've bought a few Valve Complete Pack CD-keys for Steam from game.co.uk. These bundles include 26 games. When the key is activated, the 26 games appear in your library, but there is nowhere to right-click to view the CD-key of the bundle itself. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What website did you get it from, judging by your question it isn't steam.

Comment: I believe the CD key is meant to be kept private, as valve will do most anything to your account if you provide proof that you are the owner by showing a CD key to support.

Comment: How should a CD-Key for a Bundle work ? you can access the CD key for every individual game via Right click (only if Seam enabled that option). The bundle Key you aquired form your game.co.uk side is a Steam Key that dose not have to do with any Game-Key's it is only to aktivate the specific bundle in steam like a unique identivier

Answer (score 1):

For account safety purposes, you can NOT see any CD keys after activating the game, unless the game uses the same key for activation and online play (such as Unreal Tournament series). You shouldn't need the bundle key for any other uses than proving that you own the account to Steam Support (they only ask if you activated a Retail HL2 code (the codes released on circa 2004), as far as I know).